# Control de rutas (URL) en PHP para ejecutar peticiones API

Tags: php, api

Llevo ya un rato dándole vueltas a la mejor manera de resolver esto y no doy con una solución satisfactoria.

Quisiera ejercer un control estricto sobre las rutas que se introducen en una API que estoy diseñando en mi dominio.

Hay varios puntos de entrada, por ejemplo:

- Cuando se escriba esta URL yo quiero ofrecer información general sobre el módulo `padres`:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/padres
  ```
- Cuando se escriba esta URL yo quiero ofrecer información específica sobre el `padre` con `id`  igual a `1`:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/padres/1
  ```
- Cuando se escriba esta URL yo quiero ofrecer información general sobre el módulo `colecciones`:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/padres/colecciones
  ```
- Cuando se escriba esta URL yo quiero ofrecer información específica sobre la `coleccion` con `id`  igual a `1`:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/padres/colecciones/1
  ```

Estoy capturando lo que se introduce en la URL con este código:

```
$requestUri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$arrURL = explode("/",trim($requestUri,'/'));
```

Por ejemplo, para la última URL citada, el valor de `$arrURL` sería:

```
Array
(
    [0] => padres
    [1] => colecciones
    [2] => 1
)
```

Lo que quisiera es poder controlar el contenido de `$arrURL` para, en base a él, hacer las peticiones de lugar a la base de datos o levantar Excepciones si hay URL mal escritas.

Si por ejemplo un usuario escribe esto:

```
http://www.example.com/padres/colecciones/1/ddhtfgdgj
```

Tendría este array, el cual debo identificar con una petición no válida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => padres
    [1] => colecciones
    [2] => 1
    [3] => ddhtfgdgj
)
```

He intentando creando un array que contenga los puntos de entrada, por ejemplo:

```
$arrRecursos=array('padres','colecciones');
```

y tratando de verificar si dichos puntos de entrada se encuentran en la variable `$arrURL`, pero es algo bastante tedioso, sobre todo detectar los posibles errores que el usuario pueda escribir e identificar el tipo de petición que debo ejecutar.

He intentado controlar que en `$arrURL` no haya más de 3 elementos (en ese caso toda petición sería inválida), pero me encuentro con el problema de que tanto en la petición general de `colecciones` como en la petición de un `padre` en específico el array tendría la misma cantidad de elementos y no encuentro la manera de dirigir adecuadamente los recursos con el número respectivo que se haya introducido.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera fácil y eficaz de controlar las URL y lanzar las peticiones según su contenido.

- **Nota:** Quisiera hacerlo en PHP puro, sin tener que recurrir para ello a un framework. Estoy en un dominio con hosting compartido, no quisiera tener que cargarlo con frameworks los cuales además ignoro si serían compatibles con mi proveedor de hosting.

Comment: no es la respuesta a tu problema, pero podrías echar un vistazo al framework [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) para crear las rutas API

Comment: Cualquier librería de routing (ej [fastroute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)), o un microframework que ofrezca routing (slim es excelente, secundo a @aldanux) te proveerá una sintaxis declarativa para tus rutas.

Comment: Gracias. Puse una nota al final de la pregunta. Estoy en hosting compartido. Ignoro si el proveedor admite dicho framework y preferiría hacerlo en PHP puro si fuera posible.

Comment: Podrías hacer una `pseudo-implementación` de lo que se conoce como [`permant link`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink). Es decir, podrías guardar, por ejemplo, en una tabla de la DB, la `URL` a cada contenido existente; si no esta en la tabla, entonces no existe (`throw an exception)`. Si ya estas creando un `sitemap.xml`, podrías volcar esa info a un archivo `PHP` y así te ahorras la consulta a la DB

Answer (score 2):

Una solución rudimentaria pero que podría funcionar es **adoptar la convención** de que

- el primer elemento se mapea a un controller
- el segundo un método
- el resto son argumentos

Digamos que tienes el controller `padresController.php` con un método estático `ver`. Si `ver` no recibe argumentos, despliega info general. Si recibe un argumento numérico, lo usa como $id, si el argumento es no numérico devuelve un error, y si recibe más de un parámetro, otro error.

```
class padresController {
  public static function ver($id=null) {
       if (count(func_get_args())>1) {
         echo 'este endpoint solo acepta un parámetro';
       } else if($id===null) {
         echo 'info general sobre padres';
       } else if (is_int($id)) {
         echo 'info sobre padre '.$id;
       } else {
         echo 'peticion invalida';
       }
  }
}
```

Puedes usar una función que tome el `REQUEST_URI` sin dominio (`/padres/ver/1`) y devuelva un array que contiene: `[$controller, $metodo, $argumentos]`;

```
function url_to_args($request_uri) {
    $arrURL = explode("/",trim($request_uri,'/'));  
    $argumentos = [];
    foreach ($arrURL as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == 0 || $key == 1)    {
            // no hago nada porque no son argumentos
        }     else    {
            $argumentos[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    $controller=$arrURL[0].'Controller';
    $metodo=$arrURL[1];
    return [$controller, $metodo, $argumentos];
}
```

La ruta

```
http://www.example.com/padres/ver/1
```

Debiera decirte que llames a `padresController::ver(1)` y eso lo haces con:

```
list($controller, $metodo, $argumentos) = url_to_args('/padres/ver/1');
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $metodo), $argumentos);
```

La validación del controller y el método puedes hacerlo con [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/es/function.class-exists.php) y [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/es/function.method-exists.php). El resto de las validaciones tendrías que hacerlas dentro de cada método analizando los argumentos que recibió la función estática.

También puedes usar funciones no estáticas si en vez del nombre del controller retornas una instancia de éste.

[Ejemplo funcionando](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f70e1cc6b35a4fc167ec804771ffe5f5d411bef6)

Answer (score 1):

¡¡¡Esta es una misión para [regex](https://xkcd.com/208/)!!!

```
$url   = 'http://www.example.com/padres/colecciones/1';
$regex = '~^https?://[^/]+/(?P<modulo>[-\p{L}]+)(?:/(?P<coleccion>[-\p{L}]+))?(?:/(?P<id>\d+))?/?$~i';

if (preg_match( $regex, $url, $matches)) {
    $modulo    = $matches['modulo'];
    $coleccion = isset($matches['coleccion']) ? $matches['coleccion'] : '';
    $id        = isset($matches['id']) ? $matches['id'] : '';
} else {
    // URL inválida
}
```

Si coincide, el contenido de `$matches` es:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://www.example.com/padres/colecciones/1',
  'modulo' => 'padres',
  1 => 'padres',
  'coleccion' => 'colecciones',
  2 => 'colecciones',
  'id' => '1',
  3 => '1',
)
```

Si una parte no está presente en la URL, `$matches` puede contener el valor `''` (vacío), o no tener esa clave presente (dependiendo de si es el último grupo que no coincidió).

Demo: https://ideone.com/wsc45b

---

El regex explicado:      <sup>[[regex101.com]](https://regex101.com/r/MzBf5y/1/)</sup>

```
$regex = '~
         ^                               # inicio del texto
         https?://                       # http o https
         [^/]+                           # host: cualquier caracter excepto "/"

         /                               # barra
         (?P<modulo>  [-\p{L}]+  )       # Grupo 1 "modulo": guión, letras (y diacríticos)

         (?:                             # Opcional: (grupo sin captura)
             /                           #     barra
             (?P<coleccion> [-\p{L}]+ )  #     Grupo 2 "coleccion".
         )?                              # (fin del opcional)

         (?:                             # Opcional: (grupo sin captura)
             /                           #     barra
             (?P<id>  \d+  )             #     Grupo 3 "id": dígitos
         )?                              # (fin del opcional)

         /?                              # barra al final (opcional)
         $                               # fin del texto

         # Modificadores:
         # [i] ignorar may/min
         # [x] ignorar espacios y comentariosen este regex
         ~ix';
```

<sup>- Se puede usar así, con comentarios en el código si se prefiere.</sup>

---

Esto mismo se puede hacer desde el .htaccess si te resulta más práctico:

```python
RewriteRule ^([-\wáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+)(?:/([-_a-záéíóúüñA-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+))?(?:/(\d+))?/?$ index.php?modulo=$1&coleccion=$2&id=$3 [QSA]
```